# Correct Use of live/live in

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> 1. I have a decent house to live.
> 2. I have a decent house to live in.

Which one of these sentences is correct?

Comment: What have you found to lead you toward one or the other?

Comment: Short answer: You **"live *in* a house"**, you don't **"live a house"**, so you can't drop the *in*.

Comment: @stangdon - It's not always quite that simple, though. For example, I could say, _"There is a pink flamingo outside the house we live in,"_ but I could also say _"There is a pink flamingo outside the house where we live,"_ and drop the _in_ the "where we live" version.

Comment: @J.R. - Hm, true, but that's a totally different phrasing.  The OP's sentence doesn't use that phrasing.

Comment: @J.R. Yes, *which* is the relative pronoun for NP's but *where* is the relative preposition used to replace PP's. If you only replace the NP, the preposition needs to remain. So Strangdon's point is basically correct.  :)

Comment: @stangdon - I realize the phrasing has been changed, but, if learners looked at your original explanation, there's a good chance they would think your rule applies.

Answer (score 1):

I have a house. I live in a house: a house to live in

Correct: I have a decent house **to live in**.
It comes from:
Correct: I have a decent house **in which to live**.

My children have toys. My children play with toys: toys to play with.

Another example:
My children have nice toys **with which to play**.
My children have nice toys **to play with**.

Your parents have classics. Your parents paid for classics: classics paid for.

Your parents have great hard-back classics **for which they paid**.
Your parents have great hard-back classics they **paid for**.

Summary, when there is a clause that requires a preposition + which, you can drop the which and place the preposition after the verb.